# Deploying the Redis Broker then Redis as a service onto Cloud Foundry

Tags: redis, cloud-foundry

So I am currently trying to deploy the Redis CF service onto Cloud Foundry which is on an Openstack IAAS and getting stuck with deploying the Redis Service Broker. Cloud Foundry is all set up (deployed using BOSH), but how to I deploy the broker? Is it pushed like an application? Do I need to change any files/manifests manually?

The documentation seemed a little light on how I would do this.

Answer (score 4):

Googling "Cloud Foundry Redis service broker", the first result I find is https://github.com/pivotal-cf/cf-redis-release.  This appears to document the deployment and configuration steps pretty well in its README.  You will deploy the Redis service as a BOSH deployment, and this service includes the broker.  You can drive that broker to register it with the Cloud Foundry service broker API as documented in that same README.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to handle this.

1. Run open source Cloud Foundry on top of Openstack and then deploy open source Redis (or Redis Cloud, Redis Enterprise, etc.) and connect to it using [User-Provided Service Instances](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/user-provided.html)
2. The easiest way is with a Service Broker (aka Pivotal Tile) as Amit describes in the previous answer. Run Pivotal Cloud Foundry on top of Openstack and then deploy a Redis Service Broker, such as Redis Enterprise Service Broker for Pivotal Cloud Foundry and connect to it as [documented](https://docs.pivotal.io/partners/rle-service-broker/).
3. There are other Redis service providers in the [The Foundry](https://www.cloudfoundry.org/thefoundry/): such as a9s, IBM, Redis Labs, Pivotal and Swisscom